# Insert space between hour and AMPM Designator

Tags: c#, regex

given the string "5pm" or "5am", I am trying to insert a space (whitespace) between the digit and AM/PM designator.

I have the following regex substitution

```
string pattern = @"((([1-9])|(1[0-2]))(A|P|a|p)(M|m))";
string replacement = "$1";
text = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, replacement);
```

however all this does is removes the "5pm", and replaces it with nothing (empty).

I am not sure what to put in the replacement variable to achieve my goal.

I can use the regex to get the match group, and then do some string math, to insert, but I want to learn something new in regex if this is possible.

Comment: which language is this (so that I can try out...) ?

Comment: This is for C#.

Comment: Why regex? you can do this like: `var time = "5pm";` and then `time = time.Replace("pm", " pm").Replace("am", " am")`. For clarification `Replace("pm", "<space>pm")`

Comment: @Nobody this will add additional space if the string is already have a space.

Comment: @Youssef13 That can be fixed as well: `var time = "5 pm"`. Then `time = time.Replace(" ","").Replace("pm", " pm").Replace("am", " am")`

Comment: Well, if you really want to use regexp for this, just apply small fixes: `string pattern = @"([1-9]|1[0-2])([A|P|a|p][M|m])";` `string replacement = "$1 $2";`

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria This looks promising :) Post it as answer if it's correct

Comment: @Nobody I'm not sure that this question wouldn't be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string testString = "any string here 5pM  10 Am";
testString = Regex.Replace(testString, "(\\d)(AM|PM)", "$1 $2", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Output should be:

> any string here 5 pM  10 Am

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to use a regex then the following might work: `([0-2]{0,1}[0-9])([AaPp][Mm])`. Do let me know it does.

Answer (score 0):

regex is better used where there is a more complex pattern.

`string.Replace` method is enough for the simple replacement needed.

```
var st = "5pm or 5am";
st = st.Replace("pm", " pm").Replace("am", " am");
```